# How to execute console commands before fetching local jars

Tags: gradle, command

As titled, I need to generate some jars which will then be used as local dependencies

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512117/run-a-gradle-task-before-resolving-dependencies) I tried to

```
dependencies {
    compile files("opengl.jar", "glfw.jar")
}

task generateBindings(type:Exec) {

    //on linux
    commandLine '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13/bin/jextract -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -l glut -l GLU -l GL --record-library-path -t opengl -o opengl.jar /usr/include/GL/glut.h'

    commandLine '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13/bin/jextract -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -l glfw --record-library-path -t glfw -o glfw.jar /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h'
}

compile.dependsOn generateBindings
```

but all I get is:

> Could not get unknown property 'compile' for root project 'artifact' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Project is [here](https://github.com/elect86/panama)

Am I following the right solution? If yes, how can I fix it?

If not, what shall I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `compile` task does not exist in Gradle Java plugin (see list of Java plugin tasks in [this documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks)

You need to create the dependency to your custom `generateBindings` task from a valid task, for example  `compileJava`